# In Nuxt / Electron project Typescript compiler updates watched files but does not create/rename files

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt3 and Electron project setup and I am using Typescript.  I am watching and compiling my .ts files and running nuxt/hmr and electron using the following commands.

```
"set NODE_ENV=development& concurrently --kill-others \"nuxt dev\" \"tsc-watch -p ./electron --outDir .output/electron --onSuccess run.electron\"",
```

If I update the code in a file in my project e.g. `\layouts\default.ts` the hmr works and the compiled files get updated. However if I create a new file or rename a current one it is not created or renamed.

```
 Failed to resolve import "myproject/layouts/test.vue" from "virtual:nuxt:myproject\.nuxt\layouts.mjs". Does the file exist?
```

If I run `nuxt generate` those will get built and then rerun the above command hmr works on those files as well.

It is a pain to stop the watch job run generate and then restart watch each time I create a new file, but I can't figure what I need to change.